# the_taxonomies 'template' parameter

Tags: wordpress

I checked out [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/9157/why-does-wp-get-object-terms-add-a-period-after-terms-are-output) post and saw that WP 3.1 allows you to add the parameter "template" to your 'the_taxonomies()' function - this param doesn't exist in the [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_taxonomies).

The default looks like this:

```
 the_taxonomies(array('template' => '%s: %l'));
```

Where the output is "Taxonomy Name: Taxonomy Tag." If I change it to:

```
 the_taxonomies(array('template' => '%s %l'));
```

, it removes the colon, but if I remove the %s then it only gives back the Taxonomy Name.

What I'm basically looking for is to just print out what appears to be the %l or the Taxonomy Tag.

Any ideas on this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8):

Just do that :

```
<?php the_taxonomies(array('template' => '% %l')); ?>
```

It will remove taxonomy name and will give you only the term with link.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
'template' => '%s %l'
```

Use :

```
'template' => '<div style="display:none;">%s:</div> 1%'
```

Answer (score 0):

If somebody wants to display the taxonomies without the taxonomy label and without a link then you can add term_template to the args array like the following:

```php
<?php the_taxonomies(array('template' => '% %l', 'term_template' => '%2$s')); ?>
```

This will just output the names of taxonomy without a hyperlink.